# XPATH: How can I select a Children node that contains only boy Child nodes

Tags: xpath

**I need to select a Children node that contains only boy Child nodes.**

From this XML:

```
<Parent>
    <Name>Mary</Name>
    <Sex>female</Sex>
    <Children>
        <Child>
            <Name>Joe</Name>
            <Sex>boy</Sex>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <Name>Harry</Name>
            <Sex>boy</Sex>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <Name>Sue</Name>
            <Sex>girl</Sex>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <Name>Connie</Name>
            <Sex>girl</Sex>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <Name>Kim</Name>
            <Sex>other</Sex>
        </Child>
    </Children>
</Parent>
```

I need this result:

```
<Children>
    <Child>
        <Name>Joe</Name>
        <Sex>boy</Sex>
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <Name>Harry</Name>
        <Sex>boy</Sex>
    </Child>
</Children>
```

This xpath gives me the right Child nodes - but not inside a Children node.

```
//Children/Child[Sex='boy']
```

This xpath gives me the Children node I want - but with all the Child nodes inside - not just the boys.

```
//Children[Child/Sex='boy']
```

**Can it be done with xpath?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath can give you single nodes only, not XML like this

```
<Children>
    <Child>
        <Name>Joe</Name>
        <Sex>boy</Sex>
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <Name>Harry</Name>
        <Sex>boy</Sex>
    </Child>
</Children>
```

To receive what you asking for you should use other tools, not a pure XPath.
For mode details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844276/xpath-to-get-the-entire-xml-tree-structure) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68368895/using-xpath-filter-to-get-the-entire-xml-document-structure-with-filtered-node)